# Laravel collection update item values using 'where'

Tags: php, laravel, collections, where-clause

Can you update and save a laravel collection when using a where statement eg

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
]);
```

How can i change all the prices that are 100 to 200 or product like 'Desk' to 'Cupboard'?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it by just using where, as where is made for filtering and returns items based on your predicate. Why not using a regular `array_map()` function??

```
$new_collection = array_map(function($item) {

  if($item['price'] == 100) {
     $item['price'] = 200; 
  }

  return $item;

}, $collection);
```

Comment: laravel does have a collection map function.so thats the only way? 


`$new_collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) { if($item->price == 100) { $item->price = 200; } return ['product' => $item->product, 'price' => $item->price]; });`